# Constructing find queries based on user input. The right way

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I am developing a web app using Codeigniter and MongoDB.
I need to create a function that is searching the database using the following criterias.

- Tags
- Owner username
- Status
- Date range

It needs to be flexible enough for users to for example only search by tags or status and leave out the other criterias.

Right now I am using if else structure with different queries that reflect the chosen
criterias. For example the below code. This is very bad way because then I need to create
a query matching every possible combination.

```
if ($args['status']) {

    $this->mongo_db->select ($select)->
    where('user_name', $args['username']) ->
    where ('status', $args['status']) ->
    where_in_all ('file_tags', $tags) ->
    limit ($limit) ->
    offset ($offset) ->
    get ('files');

} else {

    $this->mongo_db->select ($select)->
    where('user_name', $args['username']) ->
    where_in_all ('file_tags', $tags) ->
    limit ($limit) ->
    offset ($offset) ->
    get ('files');

}
```

Is there not a better way of doing search in MongoDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you want to create query based on user output and use it later to get data from mongoDb. Below is pseudo-code

```
if (status) {
  query.put(status, status)
}

if (tags) {
  query.put(tags, tags)
}

... etc

mongo_db->select ($query) - > limit -> offet -> get
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. I would like to avoid if/else other wise there will be too many combinations since I got 6 criteria and they could be mixed for user likings.

Comment: Ah, no I think I know what you mean. Adding to an array (query) if it exists? How would I do that in PHP in the best way?

Comment: Yes, building array dynamical and pass it as query object. Sadly, I don't how to do it better in PHP

Comment: Is it possible to do something simular with this query: where_lt ('created_at', new MongoDate (strtotime ($args['date_to']))) ->